# Shell script Fetching data from 5 different directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to run a shell script to get data from multiple directories.
My target (targetDir) has 5 directories. So the program, when executed, should search data from these 5 different directories, but when I execute it, it treats all the 5 folders same line. Any advice?

```
targetDir="snavis_bub snavis_bub2 snavis_bub3 snavis_hdw snavis_ldw"
datadir=/opt/pkg/home/tools/zform/marnel/$targetDir/of_inspect
```

Upon execute:

```
./orsInspect.sh: line 60: 
cd: /opt/pkg/home/tools/zform/marnel/snavis_bub,snavis_bub2,snavis_bub3,snavis_hdw,snavis_ldw/oref_inspect: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does my response work for you ?  I can give you more detail if you provide what you are doing in more detail .

Answer (score 0):

Many things you can do. For example you can use arrays and for loops and perform a task each iteration of the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a targetDirs=("snavis_bub" "snavis_bub2" "snavis_bub3" "snavis_hdw" "snavis_ldw")

for the_dir in "${targetDirs[@]}" ;do
    datadir="/opt/pkg/home/tools/zform/marnel/${the_dir}/of_inspect"
    echo "$datadir"
    # ... do something for each datadir
done
```

example output (just echoing):

```
/opt/pkg/home/tools/zform/marnel/snavis_bub/of_inspect
/opt/pkg/home/tools/zform/marnel/snavis_bub2/of_inspect
/opt/pkg/home/tools/zform/marnel/snavis_bub3/of_inspect
/opt/pkg/home/tools/zform/marnel/snavis_hdw/of_inspect
/opt/pkg/home/tools/zform/marnel/snavis_ldw/of_inspect
```